# How do I create a variable in the controller for single or multiple params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def index
  @users = User.all.paginate(page: params[:page])
  @users = User.named(params[:name]).paginate(page: params[:page]) if params[:name].present?
  @users = User.countryname(params[:country]).paginate(page: params[:page]) if params[:country].present?
  @users = User.gender(params[:gender_type]).paginate(page: params[:page]) if params[:gender_type].present? 
end
```

The following code works fine if only `:name` or `:country` or `:gender_type` is `present`. But it does not work if multiple params are present. What is the DRY way of writing this code for multiple params? Obviously, I do not want to create a different line of code for each possible combination of params.

Here are the scopes:

```
class User
scope :countryname, -> (country) { where("country ILIKE ?", "%#{country}%")}
scope :gender, -> (gender_type) { where gender_type: gender_type}
scope :named, -> (name) { where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{name}%")}
```

If I have a query string of

> example.com/users?name=sam&gender_type=male

it simply returns all users with names like sam and ignores their gender... I would need to code:

```
@users = User.gender(params[:gender_type]).named(params[:name]).paginate(page: params[:page]) if params[:gender_type] && params[:name].present?
```

but I do not want to have to write a new line of code for every single combination of parameters.

Comment: hmm, maybe share syntax of your scope methods ? `named`, `countryname`, `gender`

Comment: You can iterate through the params hash however due to the naming convention of your scopes you won't be able to use the key for each parameter as a call to the method without stating it explicitly first.

Comment: @bkunzi01 I don't understand "without stating it explicitly first". Please see edited question.

Comment: What is your logic for this search - are these ANDs or ORs?  For example, if the search params are `params[:gender_type] = 'male'` and `params[:countryname] = 'France'` - do you want all French males, or all French people plus all males?

Comment: @JohnFeltz ANDS

Comment: Then just chain the scopes the way ADEPOJU ADEBAYO suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was the code should be

```
@users = User.all.paginate(page: params[:page])
@users = @users.named(params[:name]).paginate(page: params[:page]) if params[:name].present? 
etc
```

Rails will then allow chain scoping automatically. the previous code creates separate independent non-chained instance variables.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the ruby `try` method. For example, you could write something like

```
@users = User.try(:gender, params[:gender_type]).try(:paginate, page: params[:page])
```

Look at [try in api docs](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/Object/try) for other ways to use it.